# Query for most used categories in a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models with a HABTM relationship between them: Feedback and Category.

Each Feedback object belongs to a Route.

I want a query that can, for each Route, show the most often selected Category for that Route's feedback.

I'm on Rails 4 and using postgresql.

Been struggling this for some time... any suggestions?

Feedback.rb

```
 class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
  belongs_to :route
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, join_table: :categories_feedbacks
 end
```

Category.rb

```
 class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :feedbacks, join_table: :categories_feedbacks
 end
```

routes_controller.rb

```
def show
 @route = Route.friendly.find(params[:id])
 @feedbacks = Feedback.where(route_id: @route.id)
 if @feedbacks.present?
  @route_score = @feedbacks.average(:rating).round(2)
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This should return the most used `category_id` in the route `@route`

```
@route.joins(feedback: :categories)
  .group_by('categories.id')
  .count.sort_by{|k,v| v}
  .first.first
```

Comment: Thanks. That is returning a NoMethodError. 'undefined method `joins' for #<Route:0x007fab5b189918>'. Investigating that...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing. I'm pretty sure there are better ways to do this, but this is working...

routes_controller.rb

```
@most_used_category = @feedbacks.joins(:categories).group('categories.id').count.sort_by{|k,v| v}.first.first
```

and in the view I show the name of the most used category...

```
<%= Category.where(id: @most_used_category).first.name %>
```